# How to extract only numbers without unwanted objects from image?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to recognize number from image using Pytesseract. So far I was able to process image like in this examples.

Example 1

Original image `->` Processed image

[image] 
[image]

Example 2

Original image `->` Processed image

[image] 
[image]

I would like to extract only numbers without unwanted objects and rotate it to improve accuracy. Do you have any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: @nathancy I've tried every method from those links but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried with the 1st link but had to add in a little bit of contour area filtering to remove the tiny noise to work

Comment: @nathancy Could you please show me how you managed to solve this problem with Example 1?

Comment: Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold, find contours, contour area filtering to remove the non-number contours (dots + random contours on the side), invert (if necessary, text has to be in foreground as black), then OCR with pytesseract

Comment: To filter out non-number contours you can 1) do aspect ratio filtering (assumption is that a number contour has larger height vs width. So if w > h then its a non-number contour. 2) contour area filtering to remove tiny noise. Pytesseract was able to read the numbers without having to do the rotation btw

Comment: @nathancy Should I resize this image? Because it's really small - 28x44. What is the best image shape to OCR? I heard something about at least 300 dpi, but I don't know how to set up this resolution.

Comment: @bedin I posted a solution, but I guess it was removed. Anyway you can add [borders](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html) for centering the image. If you resize it, your image might contain unwanted artifacts which may not give the desired results.